# MS Flow: How to achieve something like `_.find()` (lodash/JS)

Tags: power-automate, workflow-definition-language

How can I use MS Flow to select an individual object, by value for a specified property, from an array?

Example array:

```
[
  {
    item_id: '1234'
  },
  {
    item_id: '4567'
  }
]
```

In the example above, I may only want to work with the first object and the rest of its available properties.

Happy to use the Workflow Definition Language and/or any of the Data Operations actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using the "Data operations - Filter" action.
[image]

*Ignore the error in red - it is an array.*

My left-hand expression for "item_id" is:

```
item()?['item_id']
```

And then I statically enter the item ID I wish to access in the right-hand input.

DocumentNo Item will then be an array itself with only 0 or 1 elements and can be used like so:

```
body('DocumentNo_Item')?[0]?['label']
```